# Better algorithm for finding a "fit" of bit pattern in the bit string

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am facing the following problem: given a relatively short bit pattern, I want to find where it "fits" in a reasonably long bit string. By fit I mean, that for every bit, set in pattern, there's a zero in a corresponding location of a destination bit string.

For example, a pattern of `101101`, can be fitted in the following strings:

- `...00000000....` - "trivial" fit
- `...10100101....` - "exact" fit
- `...00000100....` - another useful fit

and so on.

The quality of "fit" is of no concern, first good one in bit order should do.

Clearly, a naive algorithm would work - by iteration over each 0 in the destination bit string, I can check whether a pattern fits starting from that location (adjusting for the leading bit set in pattern).

However, as we know, more specialized search algorithms achieve massive speed ups over naive implementations. Clearly, an "exact bit pattern search" algorithm would not work for this problem, but considering the gains, exact pattern search algorithms offer over naive implementations, I'm looking to see if somebody had already invested some good work into devising a better algorithm for the pattern fit problem described.

Comment: Isn't the pattern really `0x00x0` where each `0` must match a `0` in the string, and each `x` matches any character. If so, the concepts of the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm) can be applied to achieve a minor improvement in performance. I say "minor" since there's very little information gained from finding a mismatch.

Comment: It does look like a basic wildcard search (single bit wildcards). However, does KMP really applies to this problem? Most wildcard search algorithms I've seen just stick to nested loops/recursion.

Comment: I think your problem might fit better into https://cs.stackexchange.com/ as you are looking for a theoretical approach and its time complexity rather than just some working code.

Comment: I have to wonder whether you've presented the real problem that you're trying to solve. Specifically, what is the precise definition of *"relatively short"* and *"reasonably long"*? And what is the format of the input -- in other words, given that the algorithm is implemented as a function, what would the arguments to the function look like? And most importantly, is the full bit string already stored in memory, or is it being received in real time from a communication interface?

Comment: @user3386109 The pattern is few machine words in length most often, 100-300 bits. The bit string is fully stored in memory and is considered "infinite", but is on the order of few megabits.

Comment: @Socowi Actually, I was looking for an "already benchmarked" approach - something like https://github.com/almondtools/stringbench would be ideal (may be coming from the bioinformatics direction - they usually work with short alphabets like that).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much work you want to put into writing the algorithm, but what you're describing can be solved using regexes; the bit pattern `101101` corresponds with the regex `0[01]00[01]0`.

Obviously, converting the bit-string into an actual string, and then using an actual regex on it, is going to be slow. But you could use the ideas behind regexes to develop an algorithm which works directly on the bits. The key idea is to use the pattern to build a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). A DFA is a state machine which consumes the bits of your bit-string, transitioning from one state to another based on the current bit. When it reaches an "accept" state, that indicates a match was found, in a position ending at the current bit.

The simplest way to convert the pattern into the state machine is to use [Thompson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) to create an [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), then the [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to convert the NFA into a DFA. This is going to take quite a bit of effort to write the code, but the resulting state machines should be able to test bit-strings for matches and should be quite efficient if implemented carefully.

The complexity of testing a bit-string will be O(n), compared to a naive O(nk) algorithm, where n is the length of the bit-string and k is the length of the pattern. Assuming k is small and n is large, the time it takes to convert the pattern into a DFA should be negligible.

Comment: I have thought about that as well. However, it's not obvious that DFA is going to be faster than linear search on a practical machine (caches and all), while a lot of work will be necessary to implement it. Thus, the real intent of this question is to find out whether somebody had done the research and bench-marking already. For example, Thierry Lecroq had looked into precise bit string matches with some interesting results (he looked into most things related to matching, but alas, seemingly not into the variety I'm looking at now).

Comment: You could implement the state machine using a single array, where the states are numbered 0, 2, 4, 6... and each state occupies two indices in the array, for its transition on a 0 bit, and its transition on a 1 bit. The loop body would simply be `state = transitions[state | bit];`, which is one bitwise or, one array access and one assignment. If you make state 0 the "accept" state then the loop condition is `i < n && state != 0`, then after the loop there's a match ending at index `i` (exclusive) if and only if `state == 0`. For short patterns, the whole array should easily fit in L1 cache.

Comment: Test of a pattern fitness takes only few machine instructions (xor-and). Scanning the bit string linearly word by word is also very predictable for the machine. Allocating and populating a side array then jumping back and forth - not so obvious. I'm not against the DFA approach, but the prudent approach will be to implement it the simple way, then benchmark the application substantially, then possibly try the DFA (this will definitely take some time to get to).

Comment: Yes, you'd need to benchmark it to be sure. Especially if the pattern is never longer than one machine word, then you don't need a nested loop to implement the "naive" algorithm. I'll add that you don't need to implement the whole regex-to-DFA algorithm to do the benchmark; if you can use pen and paper to design a DFA for a simple test case and derive a transition array by hand, then you could benchmark that.

Comment: It is longer, more like 4 - 5 machine words (see "question" comments).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you examine the lowest bits of the bit-stream for a match, you have put a copy of them into `lowbits`.

First perform an bit-xor operation:

```
lowbits = lowbits ^ pattern;
```

this way, the bits that should be zero are turned to 1, the bits that we don't care of are unchanged.

Then perform a bit-and operation:

```
lowbits = lowbits & pattern;
```

The bits that do not count (where pattern is 0) are cleared.

You'll then get a match if and only if:

```
lowbits == pattern
```

If you do not get a match, just shift the bit-stream to the right and continue.

If the pattern fits in a hardware register, this gonna get very efficient. Else, the pattern will have to be decomposed into chunks of hardware register size, and the operation repeated on each chunk, until it fails.

There might be strategies for speeding up the shift of bit-stream (for example, for pattern of size p divided into n chunks of a register of size r, then you can take new bits from the stream every `n*r-p+1` steps, and you could instead shift the patterns left `n*r-p+1` once at the beginning of the function and keeps those `n*r-p+1` cases in memory).

Comment: "There might be strategies for speeding up" - that what this question is about.

Comment: @oakad of course. Pre-calculating copies of left-shifted pattern is the strategy I proposed. If you are clever enough, you can completely omit bit-shifting the bit-stream For example, adjust the number of chunks n so as to keep exactly r left-shifted pattern, this way the bit-stream can advance by r bits, which just mean advancing one r-bit word further. This is going to be too much machine dependent, also depending on instruction set, so I won't describe further.

Comment: I mean you'll have to try and measure by yourself.